# bibtex - endnote - new references

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies

I'm sure this has been answered somewhere else already, but still, I couldn't manage to find it out on the internet. In my group, I need to work with Endnote (on .doc files) to write shared papers. My Endnote library gets updated almost everyday with new references.

I however use Latex (TexShop) to write personal books/essays.

Since I'm updating my Endnote library everyday, I would also like to update my .bib file everyday in a parallel manner. Do I have to export the whole Endnote library everyday then, or is it possible to use some synchronization option between the two softwares?

What would be the best solution you might have in mind?
Do you think that Mendeley could be a good replacement for Endnote, and therefore easier to use/sync with Latex?

I thank you all very much in advance for your attention.

Sincerely,

Comment: Even if your Endnote database changes everyday, as long as you do note cite anything, there aren't going to be changes in your bibliography. Well, there would be if you are using `\nocite{*}`, but that would be ... not thought through.

Comment: I don't know if Mendeley is a good replacement for Endnote but I believe that it is easier to work with `.bib` files with Mendeley. (That is, I'm not sure that Endnote knows about these at all, whereas I am pretty sure Mendeley did to at least some extent when I investigated a while back.) If others in your group are open to using a different reference manager, it would almost certainly be easier than if they are wedded to Endnote. Zotero might also be worth a look.

Comment: Mendeley is described as 'Compatible with Microsoft Word, LibreOffice and BibTeX.' [here](http://www.mendeley.com/).

Answer (score 0):

My answer couldn't solve all your problems but it may be a good start.

There is a one-way bibtex to Endnote sync script, called [BibDesk2Endnote](https://github.com/peadargrant/bibdesk2endnote). I've used this Apple script and it works.

Comment: Does your script perform one-way synchronization (from bibdesk to endnote) or two-way synchronization, i.e., from endnote to bibdesk? The OP's question seemed to be mostly about endnote to bibdesk.

Answer (score 0):

Since you can export only parts of your EndNote library, you could simply sort the library by the "Last Updated" field and then only export everything that you've newly added. 
You can then just copy/paste the content of this "newly-added" bibtex file into your existing one.

You'd just need to make sure that you don't create duplicates like this.